# Consumir webService C# amsx no android volley

Tags: c#, android, json, web-service, volley

Criei um webservice em c# que me retorna uma string no padrão JSON, eu estou tentando consumir esse webservice com o volley mas o mesmo me retorna null, dependendo da variação da url ele me retorna tudo como se fosse o ?wsdl mas não a função que eu quero, é como se faltasse o click no invoke.

minha url esta assim :     url = "http://10.0.2.2/webServiceFlux/WS/SewrvicoBase.asmx?op=buscar";

já tentei variações url = "http://10.0.2.2/webServiceFlux/WS/SewrvicoBase.asmx entre outras

meu código se encontra assim:

obrigado a todos

```
package com.example.voleytest.voleytest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


       private RequestQueue queue;
    private String url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        url = "http://10.0.2.2/webServiceFlux/WS/SewrvicoBase.asmx?op=buscar";

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        callByJsonObjectRequest(null);
    }


    public void callByJsonObjectRequest(View view){

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




        }

        ) };
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rhelberth, não tenho certeza se usar o Volley puro é a melhor solução para consumir um WebService SOAP, vejo muita gente usando a biblioteca [`ksoap2`](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) ou outra biblioteca específica para tal. Talvez você possa até criar um tipo de Request/Response customizado do Volley para tornar a requisição assíncrona.

Comment: Pois é eu vi o ksoap mesmo, mas será que trabalha tão bem quanto volley?  Não gostaria de ter que mexer com trheads.

Comment: Mas se você combinar o ksoap com o Volley, usando [`Custom Requests`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) você consegue fazer a requisição assíncrona sem ter que manipular Threads explicitamente.

Comment: Então deixa eu ver se entendi, eu uso ksoap para pegar do meu webservice e depois jogo para o volley? voce tem algum exemplo tutorial ou etc? eu estava pensando em usar web API resolve o problema sera?

Comment: Sim e não. Você criaria uma "camada" em cima do Volley para fazer um Custom Request/Response para chamar o ksoap. O exemplo dessa integração tem no link que eu passei, a parte do ksoap teria que ver na documentação do repositório dele.

Comment: Certo entendi, estava acessando do celular e não tinha visto o link, obrigado pela informação, sabe me dizer se web api seria mais fácil?

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço, vamos ver se talvez alguém consiga fazer uma resposta que aborde as duas formas.